# How to create an array containing non-repeating numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers

this is my first question here.

I need to generate an array containing 16 random numbers and that's my solution:

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
```

The problem is that in this way it is possible that there are repeated numbers. Is there someone who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, not really, because op wants 16 numbers from values of 1 ... 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop

```js
const MAX_NUMBER = 16;
const arr = [];

do {

  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
  
  // Push if the array does not contain it
  if (!arr.includes(randomNumber)) {
     arr.push(randomNumber);
  }

} while (arr.length < MAX_NUMBER);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 6):

The shortest approach is to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check the wanted `size` of it.

```js
let numbers = new Set,
    result;
    
while (numbers.size < 16) numbers.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);


result = [...numbers];

console.log(...result);
```